# Change Date format in chart axis but not in excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I am trying to get a xlWorkSheet range and format it to "MMM/YYYY" in the xAxis of a chart. But I dont want to change the date format in that WorkSheet cells where I am taking the info and where I want to keep having a "MM/YYYY" format.

I've already  formatted the row to "MM/YYYY" and "MMM/YYYY", but not to use one in the excel table and the other one in just the chart.

My code is:

```
 ChartObject myChart 
Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlArea;
var yAxis = (Axis)chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
Axis.HasTitle = false;
Range chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 1], 
xlWorkSheet.Cells[rows, columns]];
Range x_Range = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, columnsCount]];
Range x_Range2 = x_Range.EntireRow.NumberFormat("MMM/YYYY");
Axis xAxis = (Axis)chartPage.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
xAxis.CategoryNames = x_Range2;

  (...series definition... and rest of code)
```